# Sqlite running error in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have to implement sqlite in my application for store some values

i got error like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[DBManager runQuery:isQueryExecutable:] in DBManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

how can i clear these kind of error.

Comment: Have you included libsqlite in your project?

Comment: Include libsqlite3.0 to your link binary section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import libsqlite3.dylib . To import this ,

1.Select Project name under targets.
2.Goto Linked frameworks and libraries.
3.Press + button and type libsqlite3.Then add it.
4.Clean and run the project.